# two operations on each element of a list

Tags: list

I would like to achieve the following lines in just one line:

```
   list1 = [abs(x) for x in list1]
   list1 = list(map(lambda x:x-1, list1))
```

I tried

```
list1 = [abs(x) and x-1  for x in list1]
```

even though I don't think there is such syntax, but anyway it didn't work.

Comment: [abs(x)-1 for x in list1] is it what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` is a logical operator in Python, it cannot be used in this condition.

why not try

```
[abs(x) - 1 for x in list1]
```

Comment: thx, do you know if we can do two operations in other cases in just one line?

Comment: @Lelo it's ok, you can use `lambda`  to do the more complicated operation in one line. And how to achieve it depends on what the problem is.

Comment: what do you mean @Lelo? You can string lambda functions together, if that interests you

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = list(map(lambda x: abs(x)-1,list1))
```

Interestingly this is slower than

```
list1 = [abs(x) - 1 for x in list1]
```

Anyone know why?